# TLB Flushing in case of process context switching

Tags: operating-system, paging, tlb

As TLB flushing in case of process context switch, why each process starts from scratch in TLB when given charge.

Why don't we fill in first few page table entries in the TLB as it can work in same fashion as we use locality of reference in memory management, i.e. when a process comes to execute, it is very likely that it will start with instruction 1 or the first instruction of the first few pages that are loaded in the main memory?

It can reduce the problem of filling up TLB during execution n speed up the system.

Answer (score 1):

**When CPU generates virtual address, The corresponding page will be searched in TLB, if it is not present in TLB, it will be searched in the next level memory, and then it will be placed in the TLB by following the suitable replacement algorithm.**

The system can't predict in which frame the page containing so called 'instruction 1' is placed. If that was the case, then there won't be any need of page replacement algorithms, Instead it can replace all the required pages sequentially like page with first instruction, page with second instruction .. and so on.